# Base Local Planner Configuration

Tags: ros, navigation, acceleration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In my deferentially steered drive system based robot my values for acceleration and deceleration are different (that was the best option, based on experimentation).

How does this affect:

```
acc_lim_x:
acc_lim_y:
```

in terms of performance?

How can I include the separation between acceleration and deceleration?

Is it recommended to always have the same value for both acceleration and deceleration? If so, why?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192207/base-local-planner-configuration/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In base local planner, there is a file called latched_stop_rotate_controller.cpp. In that function, the stop command is implemented using LatchedStopRotateController::stopWithAccLimits() [line 108] which uses acc_lim as an argument. I think you can define your own, say, decel_lim and use that instead in this function. I am not entirely sure as to whether they should be kept the same from the code's perspective though.

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0